# Dygraph text is visible through jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, dygraphs

I have Dygraph on my page, and a jQuery Datepicker to select the date range to be loaded into the Dygraph. When the data input box is clicked, the date picker pops up so the user can select a date range. 
In the  section of the html I loaded a stylesheet that made it look pretty:

The problem is that the text belonging to the Dygraph is visible through the date picker.

[Picture of problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19647566/datepicker.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit or override the `z-index` property on the CSS.

The graph title z-index should be smaller than any of the date picker.

Comment: Thanks. .ui-datepicker{ z-index: 9999 !important;} works. And the '!important' is important.